# Changing an href link to an ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, struts2

I need to change my code a little bit. My website is composed by categories and when you click on one you have the associated pdf documents.

What I'm doing right now is changing the categories by clicking on it with an href. Inside it I have an struts2 url  tag which call to a function execute.do with parameters for the category !

```
<ul>
 <#list doc as docs>
   <li>
     <a href="<@s.url includeParams="all">${docs}</@s.url>"></a>
   </li>
</#list></ul>
```

This link is executing for exemple this :

```
execute.do?s=3551f7287fa003a9&doc=E200
```

I need to avoid the refresh of the page so I clearly need ajax !

I thought to do on onclick on my categories..

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking--are you asking for a tutorial on how to do Ajax requests using jQuery or plain old JavaScript? Those exist on the web.

Comment: As per your question  I understand that you want to call your link with ajax. If yes then this link may helpful for you       
   http://ebhor.com/struts2-json-and-jquery/